# Remove backslash but keep unicode in the json string

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a json string:

```
>>> a = '[{\\\"pic\\\": \\\"QmdYSopPxh46rQ5MjyMK5uw2sBKYVwjUNVoyKFYHb1cR97\\\", \\\"note\\\": \\\"\\\\u8aaa\\\\u660e1\\\", \\\"location\\\": \\\"\\\\u6c34\\\\u6c60\\\"}, {\\\"pic\\\": \\\"QmdNGrc1S9paXycnH7ogdB8w7qDUcWnEFJMPe1Wfb9fYyP\\\", \\\"note\\\": \\\"\\\\u8aaa\\\\u660e2\\\", \\\"location\\\": \\\"\\\\u6a4b\\\\u6a11\\\"}]'
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
```

I'd like to remove the `\\` but still keep the Unicode escape sequences. Eventually use `json.loads` to convert into the python dict/list. How can I do it?

Tried three method but it didn't work:

1. `a.replace('\\', '')`

   It can remove the '\' but somehow my unicode notation is gone.

   ```
   >>> a.replace('\\', '') result seems OK but lost the unicode notation
   '[{"pic": "QmdYSopPxh46rQ5MjyMK5uw2sBKYVwjUNVoyKFYHb1cR97", "note": "u8aaau660e1", "location": "u6c34u6c60"}, {"pic": "QmdNGrc1S9paXycnH7ogdB8w7qDUcWnEFJMPe1Wfb9fYyP", "note": "u8aaau660e2", "location": "u6a4bu6a11"}]'
   ```
2. `json.loads(a)` got error message

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
   return _default_decoder.decode(s)
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
   obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
   obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
   ```
3. `a.decode('utf-8')`

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
   ```

Comment: probably, a dumb solution, but I would go with regexps to replace multiple backslashes with a single one.

Comment: Where did you get this string? From script tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd use a parser of the language in which the string was extracted from, but since you didn't mention, I resort to Python's codecs string-escape decoding to do the work. It should work for most cases, but could break in edge cases where the languages differs in the supported escape sequences.

```
import codecs
import json

s = '[{\\\"pic\\\": \\\"QmdYSopPxh46rQ5MjyMK5uw2sBKYVwjUNVoyKFYHb1cR97\\\", \\\"note\\\": \\\"\\\\u8aaa\\\\u660e1\\\", \\\"location\\\": \\\"\\\\u6c34\\\\u6c60\\\"}, {\\\"pic\\\": \\\"QmdNGrc1S9paXycnH7ogdB8w7qDUcWnEFJMPe1Wfb9fYyP\\\", \\\"note\\\": \\\"\\\\u8aaa\\\\u660e2\\\", \\\"location\\\": \\\"\\\\u6a4b\\\\u6a11\\\"}]'
unescaped = codecs.decode(s, 'unicode-escape')
obj = json.loads(unescaped)
```

Comment: I should use codecs to decode the unicode-escape first. This really helps me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to remove backslashes and keep unicode:

```
import re

a = '[{\\\"pic\\\": \\\"QmdYSopPxh46rQ5MjyMK5uw2sBKYVwjUNVoyKFYHb1cR97\\\", \\\"note\\\": \\\"\\\\u8aaa\\\\u660e1\\\", \\\"location\\\": \\\"\\\\u6c34\\\\u6c60\\\"}, {\\\"pic\\\": \\\"QmdNGrc1S9paXycnH7ogdB8w7qDUcWnEFJMPe1Wfb9fYyP\\\", \\\"note\\\": \\\"\\\\u8aaa\\\\u660e2\\\", \\\"location\\\": \\\"\\\\u6a4b\\\\u6a11\\\"}]'
print (a)
print ('\n')

b = re.sub(r'\\"', '"', a)
b = re.sub(r'\\\\u', r'\\u', b)
print (b)
```

It gives:

```
[{\"pic\": \"QmdYSopPxh46rQ5MjyMK5uw2sBKYVwjUNVoyKFYHb1cR97\", \"note\": \"\\u8aaa\\u660e1\", \"location\": \"\\u6c34\\u6c60\"}, {\"pic\": \"QmdNGrc1S9paXycnH7ogdB8w7qDUcWnEFJMPe1Wfb9fYyP\", \"note\": \"\\u8aaa\\u660e2\", \"location\": \"\\u6a4b\\u6a11\"}]

[{"pic": "QmdYSopPxh46rQ5MjyMK5uw2sBKYVwjUNVoyKFYHb1cR97", "note": "\u8aaa\u660e1", "location": "\u6c34\u6c60"}, {"pic": "QmdNGrc1S9paXycnH7ogdB8w7qDUcWnEFJMPe1Wfb9fYyP", "note": "\u8aaa\u660e2", "location": "\u6a4b\u6a11"}]
```

If you need to work with those data later, you may have issues with converting to json since you have array of 2 dictionaries. I would solve it like this:

```
import json
import re

a = '[{\\\"pic\\\": \\\"QmdYSopPxh46rQ5MjyMK5uw2sBKYVwjUNVoyKFYHb1cR97\\\", \\\"note\\\": \\\"\\\\u8aaa\\\\u660e1\\\", \\\"location\\\": \\\"\\\\u6c34\\\\u6c60\\\"}, {\\\"pic\\\": \\\"QmdNGrc1S9paXycnH7ogdB8w7qDUcWnEFJMPe1Wfb9fYyP\\\", \\\"note\\\": \\\"\\\\u8aaa\\\\u660e2\\\", \\\"location\\\": \\\"\\\\u6a4b\\\\u6a11\\\"}]'
print (a)

dictionaries = []

substrings_for_dictionaries = a.split(r'}, {')

for substring in substrings_for_dictionaries:
    substring = re.sub(r'[{}]', '', substring)
    substring = re.sub(r'[\[\]]', '', substring)
    substring = re.sub(r'\\"', '"', substring)
    substring = re.sub(r'\\\\u', r'\\u', substring)
    substring = '{' + substring + '}'
    dictionary = json.loads(substring)
    dictionaries.append(dictionary)


for dictionary in dictionaries:
    print (dictionary)
```

As a result, it gives:

```
[{\"pic\": \"QmdYSopPxh46rQ5MjyMK5uw2sBKYVwjUNVoyKFYHb1cR97\", \"note\": \"\\u8aaa\\u660e1\", \"location\": \"\\u6c34\\u6c60\"}, {\"pic\": \"QmdNGrc1S9paXycnH7ogdB8w7qDUcWnEFJMPe1Wfb9fYyP\", \"note\": \"\\u8aaa\\u660e2\", \"location\": \"\\u6a4b\\u6a11\"}]
{'pic': 'QmdYSopPxh46rQ5MjyMK5uw2sBKYVwjUNVoyKFYHb1cR97', 'note': '說明1', 'location': '水池'}
{'pic': 'QmdNGrc1S9paXycnH7ogdB8w7qDUcWnEFJMPe1Wfb9fYyP', 'note': '說明2', 'location': '橋樑'}
```

Comment: I like this suggestion. I will reference this to use on my another code. Thanks!